# Javascript html firebase returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

here is my code:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
  });
}
```

When I type that code in console, it returns me normal values (username, email and stuff)
When I put the same code in .js file included in .html it doesn't do anything.
How do I fix this? I dont even get any errors in console.

Edit:
Also after writing data in console, in the end it says "undefined"

More explanation:
I am trying to get e-mail of currently logged in user to be written in console.

Comment: Maybe you getting undefined because you are not logged in. Is there a way you can test if the user is logged in?

Comment: I logged in before redirecting to that page. If I am not logged in this wouldn't give me correct information in console when writing this directly when page is loaded.

Comment: [Why is my currentUser == null?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), "`currentUser` might be null because the `auth` object has not finished initializing".

The doc also explains that "the recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the `auth` object", as follows:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
      console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
      console.log("  Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
      console.log("  Name: " + profile.displayName);
      console.log("  Email: " + profile.email);
      console.log("  Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
    });

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: I was just about to type this too, so.. upvoted. @niks19: the problem is that in your page the code now runs before Firebase has restored the authentication state of the user, so `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null`. By the time you run the same code in the console, Firebase is likely done restoring the authentication state, and you do have a user. Using an auth state listener as Renaud shows solves that timing problem.

Comment: Sorry for being a couple of seconds faster @FrankvanPuffelen :-) Thanks for the upvote and for the precision on the console "timing".